# Prestone Power Steering with Stop Leak fluid for 2001 Jeep Cherokee XJ?

Tags: jeep, power-steering, fluid, power-steering-fluid

Is Prestone Power Steering Fluid with Stop Leak compatible with a 2001 Jeep Cherokee XJ?

Note that I'm not expecting much from "Stop Leak", but unless it harms things, it doesn't cost any extra.  Any reason not to use it if it's compatible?

If it's not compatible, is the regular Prestone Power Steering Fluid compatible?

Comment: Stop leak has chemicals that attack the hardened rubber seals to soften them in hopes of them sealing up again, problem is if there are other seals in the system that are still soft it can cause them to swell and leak, There is no such thing as a mechanic in a bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can use generic power steering fluid. I would never use a stop leak product in power steering.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you expand on that?  Why would your never use a stop leak product in power steering?

Answer (score 0):

Stop leak products can cause problems. Stop leak products work in 2 ways:

1. Particulates: basically grit that will get caught in small holes to plug them
2. Chemicals to soften seals: Old seals lose flexibility, the idea is that they "rejuvenate" old seals, making them more flexible so they do their job longer

Particulates are abrasive, and having abrasives in a system with pumps will cause damage long term. Not all stop leak products have them, so that may not be a concern. You don't want to soften seals that are already doing their job as you could end up shortening their life. The chemicals also work on other "organics" like hoses, shortening their lives as well.

If you don't have a leak in your power steering don't use a stop leak product. Use plain old power steering fluid.